# Using streamDataSource

Tags: sphinx4

I tried LatticeDemo.java. And, I could get the result as shown in the example result.
This example is using "AudioFileDataSource" for voice data (10001-90210-01803.wav).
I am trying to recognize this voice data in a different way using StreamDataSource.

But, I get a different result. I would like to hear any idea.

The following is the steps I took:

1. get Byte data from 10001-90210-01803.wav by the following code

   ```
   File f = new File(file);
   ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   BufferedInputStream in;
           try {
               in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));

               return ByteStreams.toByteArray(in);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
   ```
2. Then, just put this byte data called "data" into ByteArrayInputStream like the following

   StreamDataSource dataSource = (StreamDataSource) cm.lookup("streamDataSource");
       ByteArrayInputStream st = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
       dataSource.setInputStream(st, "Main Stream");

Actually, when we use "setInputStream" function, the second argument(i.e. "Main Stream") has special meaning? I cannot see why this argument is needed.

The configuration for streamDataSource is the following:

<component name="streamDataSource" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.util.StreamDataSource">
      <property name="sampleRate" value="16000" />
      <property name="bigendianData" value="false" />
</component>

The output is

```
Loading...
17:48:01.941 WARNING dictionary        Missing word: <unk>
17:48:02.543 WARNING dictionary        Missing word: <unk>
 <s> i. </s>
 <s> i. <sil> </s>
 <s> i. a. </s>
 <s> i. a </s>
 <s> i </s>
 <s> i a </s>
 <s> i <sil> </s>
 <s> i a. </s>
 <s> high a </s>
 <s> i </s>
 <s> a i </s>
 <s> a i. </s>
 <s> i i </s>
 <s> i i. </s>
 <s> i. </s>
 <s> i. i. </s>
 <s> high </s>
 <s> higher </s>
 <s> tight </s>
 <s> right </s>
 <s> wright </s>
I heard: i
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

> Actually, when we use "setInputStream" function, the second argument(i.e. "Main Stream") has special meaning? I cannot see why this argument is needed.

No, this argument is unused and kept for compatibility

> ```
>  <property name="bigendianData" value="false" />
> ```

Property name is bigEndianData, not bigendianData. Please also make sure you are using latest sphinx4, it's actually recommended to checkout a latest trunk from subversion.

Comment: Thank you, Nikolay. After correcting "bigendianData", I could get the good result.But, I get only the first sentence, "I heard: one zero zero zero one". So, in this case, I did not get the other setences, "I heard: analysts to one oh" and "I heard: zero one eight structure e.". But, anyway, this result sounds good to me. So, thank you

Comment: I could get all lists of speech. That was my program's problem. Thanks

Comment: But,the last sentence was different, which is "I heard: facilities rose three".

Comment: You can probably use configuration from subversion trunk, it will be a little bit more accurate.